# Appropriate data structure for storing data read from a large text file

Tags: file-io, data-structures, text-files

I need to read data from a very large (~a million entries) text file and am trying to decide which data structure is most appropriate. Each entry in the file contains two integers that represent an edge in a directed graph (the tail and the head vertices), and the vast majority of vertices have at least one outgoing edge. My "naive" solution is to use a vector of vectors, so if the tail vertex was 1 and the head vertex was 2 I'd just do something like `graph[1].push_back(2)` to read in the entry "1 2".  Once the graph is read in I'll be using Kosaraju's algorithm to compute the strongly-connected components, so I figure it will be handy to be able to access each element via the [] operator in constant time.

What are the "typical" choices in terms of data structures in a situation like this? Also, assuming the vector of vectors idea is a bad one, why is it bad? I guess the fact that they vector will need to re-size itself will slow things down, but the number of edges/vertices isn't known until runtime so I'm not sure of a way around that.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Do you know number of vertices?

Vector of vectors isn't such bad idea as you think because you can resize the outer vector before reading edges. So copying of the whole graph would be prevented.

As far as I know vector of vectors is good structure for graph. It is often used on olympiads on computer science.